# there is zxing lib x86_64?

Tags: android, x86-64, zxing, lib

Guys need help there is zxing lib x86_64?

[lib file folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xebgA.png)

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(BinaryBitmap.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(LuminanceSource.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(MultiFormatReader.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(Result.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(HybridBinarizer.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/lib
>   zxing.a(Str.o): incompatible target
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:29: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:46: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:46: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:46: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:27: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::MultiFormatReader::MultiFormatReader()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:30: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::HybridBinarizer::HybridBinarizer(zxing::Ref)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:31: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::BinaryBitmap::BinaryBitmap(zxing::Ref)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:38: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:39: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getText()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:39: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::String::getText() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:40: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getResultPoints()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::MultiFormatReader::MultiFormatReader()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:57: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::HybridBinarizer::HybridBinarizer(zxing::Ref)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:58: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::BinaryBitmap::BinaryBitmap(zxing::Ref)'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:60: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:64: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getText()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::String::getText() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/zxingscanner.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getResultPoints()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXingForUE4/Private/LuminanceSourceCreator.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cppx6.o:D:/Program Files/Unreal Projects/Project/Intermediate/Build/Android/TouchFox/Shipping/ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cpp:vtable for TextureLuminanceSource: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::isCropSupported() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cppx6.o:D:/Program Files/Unreal Projects/Project/Intermediate/Build/Android/TouchFox/Shipping/ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cpp:vtable for TextureLuminanceSource: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::crop(int, int, int, int) const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cppx6.o:D:/Program Files/Unreal Projects/Project/Intermediate/Build/Android/TouchFox/Shipping/ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cpp:vtable for TextureLuminanceSource: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::isRotateSupported() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cppx6.o:D:/Program Files/Unreal Projects/Project/Intermediate/Build/Android/TouchFox/Shipping/ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cpp:vtable for TextureLuminanceSource: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::invert() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cppx6.o:D:/Program Files/Unreal Projects/Project/Intermediate/Build/Android/TouchFox/Shipping/ZXingForUE4/Module.ZXingForUE4.cpp:vtable for TextureLuminanceSource: error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::rotateCounterClockwise() const'
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)):     clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(BinaryBitmap.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(LuminanceSource.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(MultiFormatReader.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(Result.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(HybridBinarizer.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: D:/Program Files/Epic Games/UnrealEngine-4.23/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/ZXing/Source/ZXing/lib/Android/local/armeabi-v7a/libzxing.a(Str.o): incompatible target
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::LuminanceSource(int, int)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::MultiFormatReader::MultiFormatReader()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::HybridBinarizer::HybridBinarizer(zxing::Ref)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::BinaryBitmap::BinaryBitmap(zxing::Ref)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getText()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::String::getText() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getResultPoints()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::MultiFormatReader::MultiFormatReader()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::HybridBinarizer::HybridBinarizer(zxing::Ref)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::BinaryBitmap::BinaryBitmap(zxing::Ref)'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getBarcodeFormat() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getText()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::String::getText() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::Result::getResultPoints()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::~LuminanceSource()'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::isCropSupported() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::crop(int, int, int, int) const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::isRotateSupported() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::invert() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: undefined reference to 'zxing::LuminanceSource::rotateCounterClockwise() const'
>   PackagingResults: Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)): Took 1118,4048375s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (D:\Program Files\Epic Games\UnrealEngine-4.23\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Logs\UBT-TouchFox-Android-Shipping_2.txt)
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
>   UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1a,ETC1)): BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build version 1.0.7 from https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp using MinGW-w64+GCC (from: http://winlibs.com/) under MSYS2.

Here is how I built both static and shared libraries:

```
wget https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp/archive/v1.0.7.tar.gz
tar v1.0.7.tar.gz
cd zxing-cpp-1.0.7
cp -f core/CMakeLists.txt core/CMakeLists.txt.bak &&
mkdir -p build_static build_shared &&
 #sed -e "s/add_library *([^ ]*$/& STATIC/" core/CMakeLists.txt.bak > core/CMakeLists.txt &&
 cd build_static &&
 cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DENABLE_DECODERS:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_ENCODERS:BOOL=ON ../core &&
 cd .. &&
 make -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
 sed -e "s/add_library *([^ ]*$/& SHARED/" core/CMakeLists.txt.bak > core/CMakeLists.txt &&
 cd build_shared &&
 cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DENABLE_DECODERS:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_ENCODERS:BOOL=ON ../core &&
 cd .. &&
 make -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
 echo Success (check /usr/local)
```

Replace `/usr/local` in the code above to suit your desired installation location.